# Analytic region problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am asked to express the function in terms of $u(x,y) +iv(x,y), z=x+iy$ and then determine the region where f is analytic.

The function is: $f(z)=e^{z^2}$

I found $f(z)$ expressed in terms of $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ is:
$$
f(z)=e^{x^2-y^2}cos(2xy)+ie^{x^2-y^2}sin(2xy)
$$
For this example I am confused as to what the analytic region would be, if someone could explain this to me it would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the context, I think you are being asked to verify that the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at every point. You should expect this because $f$ is a composition of two analytic functions.